# Can't solve this equation to $\phi$

Tags: trigonometry

It's the end of a Physics Problem.
2 Forces are equal, one is proportional to $\sin\phi$ the other to $$\frac{\cos\phi}{\text{distance}^2}$$
distance is proportional to $\sin\phi$ $$$$
I'm stuck at this last equation
$$\frac{\sin^3\phi}{\cos\phi}=c$$

Answer (score 1):

Try restating all the "proportional to"'s as equalities, by inserting proportionality constants c_n. Then collect the named constants together and replace them with "c".

Comment: But there is only one c for all the equals left. I don't get what u mean

Comment: Try following the recipe instead of throwing your hands in the air saying "I can't!"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it to 
$$\phi=\arcsin x$$
$$\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=c$$
$$\frac{x^6}{1-x^2}=c^2$$
But I think one can only solve this numerical